# Installer of Oracle jdk-7u45-macosx-x64 hangs on Mavericks

Tags: macos, java

I want to install Java 7 on my Mac which was updated to Mavericks. I downloaded the [jdk package from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and after starting the installer I exactly to this point

[image]

Pressing now `Install` does nothing and I can only close the installer.

Has someone an idea how to resolve this issue or how to track it down?

### Edit

Here is all log-information which can be accessed through ⌘L. Unfortunately, the complete list you see below is already printed *before* I press the Install button. This means, after pressing Install simply nothing seems to happen.

```
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: LSExceptions [0x7fd8eaa009a0] loaded
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-845
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-721
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Hardware: MacPro4,1 @ 2.92 GHz (x 16), 16384 MB RAM
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.119/tbb/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.119/compiler/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.119/ipp/../compiler/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.119/ipp/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.119/compiler/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.119/mkl/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.119/tbb/lib
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/km/9hdvqhk90p3gn3bm1f0xmytr0000gn/T/
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: HOME=/Users/patrick
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: USER=patrick
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: LOGNAME=patrick
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-HOL3Ae/Listeners
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-EpWqi0/Render
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: __CHECKFIX1436934=1
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: JDK 7 Update 45  Installation Log
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Opened from: /Volumes/JDK 7 Update 45/JDK 7 Update 45.pkg
Dec  6 17:09:26 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: Product archive /Volumes/JDK 7 Update 45/JDK 7 Update 45.pkg trustLevel=202
Dec  6 17:09:36 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: LSExceptions [0x7fd8eaa009a0] unloaded
Dec  6 17:09:38 sheldor.local Installer[12875]: InstallerStatusNotifications plugin loaded
```

Comment: Open the installer, press ⌘L to show the logs, then change the Detail Level to Show All Logs. Try to install and see what the log says.

Comment: @grgarside I have added the log messages to the question. Unfortunately, they don't help very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem in the meantime. Some days after posting this question, I tried to install a new version of the Adobe Suite and I noticed that I was unable to uninstall the old version with kind of the same behaviour as described for the Java installer.

Therefore, I decided to make a fresh install of Mavericks. After that, not only the installing issues were gone, but additionally the [*Finder freezes*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/121484/37046) don't appear any more.

Concluding, it seems to me that making only an update when switching to Mavericks shouldn't probably be done if making a backup and fresh install isn't too much work. Looking back, it would have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You could always proceed at your own risk to install the package using Pacifist, a free download that asks you to donate, as I have done before with Java. It just places the files in and doesn't ask questions, and then you reboot… Really, proceed with caution if you do that. It worked for me on the JDK, but I was in a slightly different situation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I completely forgot to give feedback on my question here, because I already solved it. It seemed that my system was heavily damaged after the update, because what I noticed later was that I'm not only unable to install Java, I was even unable to uninstall the Adobe Creative Suite. Therefore, I reinstalled the system completely and now all those issues are gone.

Comment: Btw, you get a +1 because I didn't know about Pacifist.