# Finder Continually Freezing

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, performance

I have a problem with the Finder App in Mac OS 10.9.4 where the finder will freeze after a few minutes. This is very similar to the issue here: [Finder slow/freeze under Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121484/finder-slow-freeze-under-mavericks)
In fact, deleting the plist file resolves the issue. But only for a few minutes then the freeze comes back.

What I have just noticed now though, is that I don't think Finder is freezing, but rather the display is not updating. I think this because I can open the Finder while it works, select a file, wait for it to freeze - click some else in the window to confirm - click on a file, then press "return". Here the change file name action will occur, the part of the window will "unfreeze" and the highlighted filename will appear and be changeable. Press enter and it will "freeze" again.

I should point out that this is currently occurring on a brand new macbook pro with 10.9.4 installed about 2 days ago. I used the migration assistant to copy data from my old macbook to this one. And the problem was also occurring on the old macbook.

I can't think of anything I installed that would cause this and I think I'm up to date.

Edit:
Console output every time I click on the window

```
7/10/2014 2:20:53.163 pm Finder[777]: -[__NSCFString hasPrefix:]: nil argument
7/10/2014 2:20:53.166 pm Finder[777]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90e6a25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f768e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90e6a10c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90d8332a -[__NSCFString hasPrefix:] + 90
    4   FinderExt                           0x0000000101312693 vLogDebug + 617
    5   Finder                              0x0000000100cd8fcc Finder + 1073100
    6   Finder                              0x0000000100cd8f29 Finder + 1072937
    7   Finder                              0x0000000100cd8407 Finder + 1070087
    8   Finder                              0x0000000100cd7d5f Finder + 1068383
    9   Finder                              0x0000000100cd7c27 Finder + 1068071
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b147468 -[NSControl drawRect:] + 341
    11  Finder                              0x0000000100c1c54c Finder + 300364
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b13a04f -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3748
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b1388c4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1799
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b138ca0 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b138ca0 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b138ca0 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b138ca0 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b136706 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 841
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3181e2 -[NSBrowser _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 80
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b137bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b135eb1 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b132e9f -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2828
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b1122da -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1680
    31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b17774e _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 884
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b74d061 __83-[NSWindow _postWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled]_block_invoke1331 + 46
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90d9ad67 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90d9acd7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90d8c3b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90d8be75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff90a13a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff90a13685 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
    39  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff90a135bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff8afdb24e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff8afda89b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff8afce99c -[NSApplication run] + 553
    43  AppKit                              0x00007fff8afb9783 NSApplicationMain + 940
    44  Finder                              0x0000000100bd9730 Finder + 26416
    45  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff85c805fd start + 1
)
```

Comment: Do you get some errors in Console.app ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: added output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was created because either the Google Drive App or the Dropbox App lost their download directories. But the shortcut links were still in Finder on the left.
Once I removed the shortcuts to these folders the issue was resolved.

Not sure of the technical details behind it, but something to check for next time.

Comment: Yes, confirmed I turned of google drive and it works

Answer (score 0):

After a similar experience with 10.9.5 (MBA mid-2012 13") I booted into [Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564?viewlocale=en_US) and then back to a normal boot.  This resolved the issue.

Comment: I've rebooted and the problem persists. And over two computers. This makes me believe I've messed up a setting some where/how

Comment: Did you reboot in Safe Mode?  You might try Onyx or a similar tool to clear caches (esp. Launch Services, the Dynamic Loader (dyld), and icon cache).  **Be sure you have a backup** before working with this, and running the tool while in Safe Mode can avoid interactions with other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Backup & Sync utility's finder extension that shows status often is the problem. It's easy to turn it off within the app and Finder seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

I tried removing Google drive, also reinstalling OS and repairing permissions. Nothing worked so I installed a 3rd party app to do the job of finder instead

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/commander-one-free-dual-pane/id1035236694?mt=12

It's working fine so far